# Docker container run with -p flags raise driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: docker

When I using the following command to create container, everything works well.

```
→ docker container run hello-world
```

But when I add the -p flags. Here comes the error.

```
→ docker container run -p 8123:8123 hello-world

Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint magical_noyce (e6394c852520bfe321a9023d510a4caf35c8fd415e9f8962ed2690e3b2a202b6): Error starting userland proxy:.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

Try this command and get the same error.

```
→ docker container run -p 8124:8213 hello-world

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint reverent_kepler (dacc9951d59d436c3fc0a73e9944210431b9dd5a8260a86cd89d8a97ef359570): Error starting userland proxy:.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

What I've tried and none of them work.

1. Try the other port and get the same results. There is no service using the selected.
2. Turn off the ufw and still get the same results.
3. Restart the docker service
4. Reinstall the docker

Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.7
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.21.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 14
  Running: 5
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 9
 Images: 12
 Server Version: 24.0.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 nvidia runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d8f198a4ed8892c764191ef7b3b06d8a2eeb5c7f
 runc version: v1.1.10-0-g18a0cb0
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-89-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 24
 Total Memory: 251.3GiB
 Name: server
 ID: 2da3333d-662d-4887-a109-2286bf0ed703
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: ******
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Docker network ls

```
→ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME               DRIVER    SCOPE
8916f6000270   bridge             bridge    local
58facbe39dfc   my-service1        bridge    local
5f625a035c6a   host               host      local
43aa52a417e3   my-service2        bridge    local
f3c698201b92   none               null      local
```

Expected the following cammand can work and don't raise any error.

```
docker container run -p 8123:8123 hello-world
```

System

```
Ubuntu 20.04
```

I've tried reinstall docker, restart docker.

---

**Update-1**

journalctl -xu docker.service results.

```
十一 28 13:30:15 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:30:15.750471849+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 9123-9123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:30:15 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:30:15.946113898+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/bd99a2ff7b6fcb52e76f9d8d68697f826bc6d778fc4a4ecfab15479425308803/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint darde (194a713c098895225bb06d86d51bac51149c2649ba80213f1eca252969ca710a): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:38:32 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:38:32.038982022+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 9123-9123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:38:32 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:38:32.254256286+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/90c010f69edc6899364f6eb06576b34852ffdac49cc0967f59da45ef8bdae760/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint darde (cead79c730fa701e364c77f0d074996b0d59f2e52b1c2d2ec50e7426511fef59): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:38:42 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:38:42.644142365+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 9123-9123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:38:42 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:38:42.849615955+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/062467e7b81ffe628d02b0c1de68a604a19d578222b551b3b202286a8936c270/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint darde (b90f45558b2e89efeeca5cfec48a1d0648df45138d7293b08138fee10123e7f5): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:39:33 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:39:33.273052754+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
十一 28 13:39:33 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:39:33.273107538+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
十一 28 13:40:36 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:40:36.087591783+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 9123-9123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:40:36 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:40:36.249959124+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/8c0dcccc88cb4ecd82fce235a974b38d9776d25e5cd5ae7276c31712fd0d5649/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint darde (d5310061cb77cf22974e1e621f2492700683912bb84066972ceffb216305dab7): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:40:43 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:40:43.715407826+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 9123-9123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:40:43 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:40:43.929171885+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/7d2afa5d0b129b5d9ec5a013fe328290b55d2cab7121eae315c3c650e1f88073/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cde (1034727d679830ca6dac1efe9b9fb0ed44d274467154f0da7f5178eef83d9745): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:41:01 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:41:01.708842224+08:00" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: context canceled"
十一 28 13:41:02 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:41:02.721431247+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=76964c2553ff1038899e23afd2ae6c3a126f2a6581078dda0dd96e2f0a18b28f module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
十一 28 13:41:02 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:41:02.734718516+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to close stdin: task 76964c2553ff1038899e23afd2ae6c3a126f2a6581078dda0dd96e2f0a18b28f not found: not found"
十一 28 13:42:58 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:42:58.492014168+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
十一 28 13:42:58 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:42:58.492061949+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
十一 28 13:44:15 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:44:15.188749395+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=6f2f6c304b4c7c3f24cc19bcd56bce21d328e7c52b584d77e9b14ce91bcb1bff module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
十一 28 13:44:15 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:44:15.207171919+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to close stdin: task 6f2f6c304b4c7c3f24cc19bcd56bce21d328e7c52b584d77e9b14ce91bcb1bff not found: not found"
十一 28 13:49:15 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:49:15.687517775+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=81c7a45a76c896fde45f009a06514db21266009e0344a8a482d260ecdb163b29 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
十一 28 13:49:15 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:49:15.705243217+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to close stdin: task 81c7a45a76c896fde45f009a06514db21266009e0344a8a482d260ecdb163b29 not found: not found"
十一 28 13:49:32 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:49:32.903263135+08:00" level=warning msg="reference for unknown type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws" digest="sha256:afea7dbd06940b9979cec0f1b9e8ccb7111d6feb671687ba9281a57136c1564e" remote="docker.io/bobrik/socat:latest"
十一 28 13:49:33 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:49:33.529827561+08:00" level=warning msg="Error persisting manifest" digest="sha256:afea7dbd06940b9979cec0f1b9e8ccb7111d6feb671687ba9281a57136c1564e" error="error committing manifest to content store: commit failed: unexpected commit digest sha256:969df6d67943f428b817e2a6ee56aa37d637836f79962cd1f29f1c8b7552fc87, expected sha256:afea7dbd06940b9979cec0f1b9e8ccb7111d6feb671687ba9281a57136c1564e: failed precondition" remote="docker.io/bobrik/socat:latest"
十一 28 13:49:33 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:49:33.529899307+08:00" level=warning msg="[DEPRECATION NOTICE] Docker Image Format v1, and Docker Image manifest version 2, schema 1 support will be removed in an upcoming release. Suggest the author of docker.io/bobrik/socat:latest to upgrade the image to the OCI Format, or Docker Image manifest v2, schema 2. More information at https://docs.docker.com/go/deprecated-image-specs/"
十一 28 13:50:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:50:03.122096797+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
十一 28 13:50:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:50:03.122139639+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
十一 28 13:50:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:50:03.257219936+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
十一 28 13:50:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:50:03.257253955+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
十一 28 13:50:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:50:03.266219214+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
十一 28 13:50:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:50:03.266264507+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
十一 28 13:50:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:50:03.332834272+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 2376-2376: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:50:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:50:03.516225119+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/568d9f1792969b9a305710be4938be521f427c041cd9f864b828daff669dc915/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mlops-docker-proxy-1 (f36356a307e635239fc679ac0251bdfebad3550be7c60460f5d0b1f7fc99ab96): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:58:27 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:58:27.862716523+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 123-123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:58:28 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:58:28.063367974+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/beeaa5d216d86ec8e51ee3a873b25dbd4bf640456bbf2996e71a92b6216d392b/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint darde (ed3ee688507712bfbd8f0dada5b37e3ad4a669babf6f50811d289e1118ed44e5): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:59:39 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:59:39.816794664+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 9123-9123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 13:59:40 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T13:59:40.035854536+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/6cbf432b57cb01cd02174673d4de41d68bc3d73b7c1abe3874486d70b91b16eb/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gg (0eaaeaaa07ccaa300926b41dde25ce850d74c8838f5ee7b2b3e63834f2ad202b): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 14:17:01 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:17:01.071893107+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=223088e7052314820735dc23762840dc797bdcbea17925d1722a88b9c958121f module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
十一 28 14:17:01 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:17:01.089673643+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to close stdin: task 223088e7052314820735dc23762840dc797bdcbea17925d1722a88b9c958121f not found: not found"
十一 28 14:30:04 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:30:04.905463198+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 7777-7777: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 14:30:05 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:30:05.120407874+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/bbbd7a97e355d65aa062e8f45c2e148b0a7810e250542f709083a13d8ffc1f72/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint inspiring_burnell (b414da1badebcf633b787a5d1b472049b84de244ccf994f4b2152940e6ecb15e): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 14:30:26 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:30:26.844001382+08:00" level=warning msg="no trace recorder found, skipping"
十一 28 14:40:24 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:40:24.185021726+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 7777-7777: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 14:40:24 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:40:24.374380072+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/c1c2e41d31193ae0d28fe2b87cb934d02d6caa42428c7ee1e22a2a1226fc2598/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint stupefied_hertz (255b594d9f71275bac77da859f1c5e4a37d2c26edd3e42defb5a0aae1a0c9eb2): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 14:56:57 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:56:57.145786337+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=51ded6ddcfeffb88c4977aeefb99c5327161cb5e4a9ad3feb9c00dd4e9bca985 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
十一 28 14:56:57 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:56:57.163895130+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to close stdin: task 51ded6ddcfeffb88c4977aeefb99c5327161cb5e4a9ad3feb9c00dd4e9bca985 not found: not found"
十一 28 14:57:46 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:57:46.828957037+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1e9108573a3704a883e1d504b175a4f3f11f1e36583e5f1429a583850bad0890 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
十一 28 14:57:46 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T14:57:46.848596903+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to close stdin: task 1e9108573a3704a883e1d504b175a4f3f11f1e36583e5f1429a583850bad0890 not found: not found"
十一 28 15:14:17 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T15:14:17.485898985+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/create returned error: invalid volume specification: '/data3:data3': invalid mount config for type \"bind\": invalid mount path: 'data3' mount path must be absolute"
十一 28 15:36:33 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T15:36:33.595098620+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 7890-7890: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 15:36:33 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T15:36:33.854290436+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/417f42f7701bb6d4744d98b4df7feb31c6e4a23674461569a3ee9b5ad427373e/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint darde (84945ce82d0b62d8c08b5ebaf5aca640e52988f99e7d59b0969ee529fb110f4e): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 15:40:37 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T15:40:37.016939660+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 7890-7890: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 15:40:37 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T15:40:37.199000214+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/447721617a3b72e826fbc3889441a26897a239dd13f4602d58c3deb9ee082d59/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint darde (1d90efb9e9e8609eebf05f193714c18c2ec3bba00925c44997658da79b9a2ac1): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 15:50:00 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T15:50:00.841286980+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 5888-5888: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 15:50:01 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T15:50:01.039041055+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/c4433d818337f3ab62ae61076434cb16d816b276a8b7a2e48fa8d57de95fb731/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint scott_tf2_dev (6117ed28e419a4c5836dbe32c9bb1b450096fd70a3566fa6f8c0856d91b3c8a1): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 16:09:04 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T16:09:04.648629066+08:00" level=warning msg="no trace recorder found, skipping"
十一 28 16:28:19 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T16:28:19.388588662+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 5888-5888: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 16:28:19 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T16:28:19.550759696+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/scott_tf2_dev/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint scott_tf2_dev (c4b269a836b23a13dfccd521dd19bef15b928c7a73b30f70ee5e27d8ebce996a): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 16:42:47 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T16:42:47.036579914+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 5888-5888: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 16:42:47 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T16:42:47.326785035+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/c4433d818337f3ab62ae61076434cb16d816b276a8b7a2e48fa8d57de95fb731/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint scott_tf2_dev (11229c581a0fe67f578b6abfa9c3a14fa90686801215734757d5782a8d3b9083): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 16:42:59 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T16:42:59.256623866+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 5888-5888: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 16:42:59 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T16:42:59.457822478+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/c4433d818337f3ab62ae61076434cb16d816b276a8b7a2e48fa8d57de95fb731/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint scott_tf2_dev (61087f263f362eb3e7d320938030b8f22537fd5afad113a99579659e025ca5e7): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 17:54:23 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T17:54:23.579822745+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=38acd2d6d9839460b5f34b5f7142d4956880192dfc7bfdd5ad4fea3b9ae9925b module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
十一 28 17:54:23 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T17:54:23.600119909+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to close stdin: task 38acd2d6d9839460b5f34b5f7142d4956880192dfc7bfdd5ad4fea3b9ae9925b not found: not found"
十一 28 22:25:45 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T22:25:45.714062163+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=2ea1045164ce4628a26fbad98c0f7e19e1bbc2bf43f9cdeb1d03ea182d503bc0 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
十一 28 22:27:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T22:27:03.301895518+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 8123-8123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 22:27:03 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T22:27:03.610159202+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/e5211c362defe7f6d8c5ef3957fe4d24e0326e4657a355c9f74bb3eb9e5b78de/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint magical_noyce (e6394c852520bfe321a9023d510a4caf35c8fd415e9f8962ed2690e3b2a202b6): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 23:01:55 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T23:01:55.687420256+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 8124-8124: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 23:01:55 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T23:01:55.891477925+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/ce46cfb8c2a1afb5cce4d1d01f51b28c492cce97b24bacae95c7309581bcdcd1/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint reverent_kepler (dacc9951d59d436c3fc0a73e9944210431b9dd5a8260a86cd89d8a97ef359570): Error starting userland proxy: "
```

How I install the docker?
Follow the docker web
Remove old package

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
```

Install

```
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME") stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

---

**Update-2**

1. Find something wired. docker-proxy uses lots of cpu
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQVhP.png)

```
 PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
   1332 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 S 1132  0.1     242h /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
 681842 *******    20   0 64.0G 15.9G 5095M S 242.  6.3 61h20:41 python src/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir /workspace/models/**** --pipeline_config_path /workspace/pretrained_models/
1959338 root       20   0 75.8G 14.4G 1040M S 170.  5.7 20h00:57 python scripts/train.py --user_define_config config/model_config.ini
  16047 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 97.1  0.1 19h02:10 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16054 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 95.3  0.1 22h26:46 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16053 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 93.5  0.1 22h27:17 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16045 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 95.9  0.1 18h59:54 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16052 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 92.3  0.1 19h12:37 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16051 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 94.7  0.1 19h15:20 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16050 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 100.  0.1 19h10:06 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16046 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 91.1  0.1 19h07:14 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16048 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 92.3  0.1 19h03:54 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16056 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 90.6  0.1 22h30:37 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16049 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 98.2  0.1 19h09:24 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
  16055 root       20   0 2428M  285M     8 R 92.9  0.1 22h27:04 /usr/sbin/docker-proxy --daemonized
```

2. update some missing parts of journalctl. Due to the character limits of the post, I can't add more logs.

```
十一 28 11:43:09 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:43:09.728407745+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
十一 28 11:43:09 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:43:09.729462149+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/images/create returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
十一 28 11:44:14 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:44:14.083024741+08:00" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
十一 28 11:44:14 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:44:14.083075526+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
十一 28 11:44:14 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:44:14.084040849+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/images/create returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
十一 28 11:45:41 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:45:41.046532253+08:00" level=warning msg="no trace recorder found, skipping"
十一 28 11:46:12 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:46:12.051989461+08:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 123-123: Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 11:46:12 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:46:12.262158323+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/containers/94e5402c86d13617bb17267ab11abbf9568ba43a14879e7bf35af3b434846ed5/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint darde (685e5a94f837c9092ca4b0500330fbf2ade50a2aa8c743c9b50a6d2dfd2b0c82): Error starting userland proxy: "
十一 28 11:55:20 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T11:55:20.386814962+08:00" level=warning msg="no trace recorder found, skipping"
十一 28 12:11:46 server dockerd[37232]: time="2023-11-28T12:11:46.748199118+08:00" level=warning msg="no trace recorder found, skipping"
```

Comment: What is your OS and how did you install docker?

Comment: @Andy are you running in WSL or Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Also, share how this problem is related to programming

Comment: The first message on your journalctl is an error. Do you have something before it?

Comment: @Andy Docker engine version 24.0.7 was [released yesterday](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/24.0/#2407). Can you delete this and try to install an older version that is say 3-4 months older? I would also report this to docker devs [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues).

Comment: A1: I will update the journalctl to my original post.
A2: Yes I can try to install the older version, but it takes some time to do that. I'll do it ASAP